# Websockets behavior when the SSL certificate expires

Tags: ssl, websocket

A web app uses an SSL-encrypted WebSocket to communicate with a web server (`wss://`). Imagine a situation when the certificate expires some time after the socket is open.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177075/ssl-certificate-expires-while-connected), for a regular communication with HTTPS without websockets this does not seem to be a problem, as far as the certificate validity is checked at the TLS/SSL handshake at the beginning.

Since the sockets assume some persistence and may remain open for a long time, I am wondering what would happen on the client side in this situation.

How a modern web-browser would behave? Do we need to treat this corner case with a particular care, i.e., meter programmatically the expiration time and force the websocket to reconnect when the moment comes, assuming the certificate has been updated on the server some time before)?

Comment: In short: certificate is only checked inside the TLS handshake. This is true for websockets too. Apart from that the certificate check is done to authenticate the server, thus checking it is only relevant when connecting to the server and not when keeping an established connection open. The server will not change underneath if the certificate expired.